# Is it possible to connect asp.net core 2.1 web api with existing database in sql server?

Tags: c#, database-connection, asp.net-core-webapi

I see an official video of visual studio show how to do this. But in the end, the instructor can't make it work, he must alter UseSqlServer() with UseInMemoryDatabase() in Startup.cs.

Here is my code, i follow his instruction.
Firstly, create a file with classes that one contain Dbcontext, others map with tables in database. In my case, database just have one table: Students. This is class contain Dbcontext:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HoangHoaTham.WebAPI.Entities
{
    public class TodoContext : DbContext
    {
        public TodoContext(DbContextOptions<TodoContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Students> Students;
    }
}
```

My Startup.cs, i add UseSqlServer here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using HoangHoaTham.WebAPI.Entities;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

namespace HoangHoaTham
{
    public class Startup
    {   
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<TodoContext>(options
                => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("HoangHoaTham")));



            services.AddMvc();
        }

        //You don't need to reed the code below

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, I add ConnectionString into appsetting.json:

```
{
  "ConnectionString": {
    "HoangHoaTham": "Server=PC-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=HoangHoaThamHighSchool;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
}
```

Anh it doesn't work. The error :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e13pT.png)

Here is his video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aIkpVzqLuhA
Skip to 50:47 to see how he did that.
Thank you so much.

Comment: So what is your issue in your question?

Comment: I want to know whether .net core web can't actually connect with sql server, or i miss up something to do it successfully

Comment: Yes is the answer. If you've connection exception you should post the error message in your question.

Comment: Have you tried your code. Does it work. The problem in his video is some permisison issue or so. Maybe you don't have this on your PC.

Comment: is your PC really called PC-PC ?? do you have SQL express or SQL developer?

Comment: I have SQL express.

Comment: Also, sorry for being unclear. I add a picture of an error i commit in my post.

Comment: My code didn't work, and i check it carefully. I actually just want to know is it possible to connect .net core web api with sql server or i did the impossible thing. That's my point.

Answer (score 2):

The error is telling you that the result of `Configuration.GetConnectionString("HoangHoaTham")` is `null`. Therefore, there's some issue with your configuration, and it turns out there is: the connection string section in appsettings.json is supposed to be `ConnectionStrings` (plural). You've got `ConnectionString` (singular) instead.

Comment: It's a part of my error. I also forgot to add {get;set;} in Dbset<Students>Students , so it does't work. Now it works, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The error is for the `ConnectionString` you used in `appsetting.json` just try this code in your `appsetting.json1 and tweak the` connectionstring` as per your requirements this would work.

## ASP.NET Core Web API

```
{
   "ApplicationInsights":{
      "InstrumentationKey":""
   },
   "ConnectionStrings":{
      "DefaultConnection":"Server=srvrName;Database=Test;User Id=User;Password=pass"
   },
   "Logging":{
      "LogLevel":{
         "Default":"Warning"
      }
   },
   "AllowedHosts":"*"
}
```